# Angular fails at image upload

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, angular-validation

I have an angular app where i need to upload an image to the server (node backend). I tried different methods i found on internet but i have the same problem with all of them: the server is not receiving the image. If i use plain HTML form the server works flawlessly, i even changed the server library from multer to express-upload but the problem persists so i'm pretty sure this is an angular problem.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="imageForm" *ngIf="state == 2" (ngSubmit)="uploadImage()">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <ngx-mat-file-input formControlName="image" placeholder="Imagen" accept="image/*"></ngx-mat-file-input>
        <mat-icon matSuffix color="primary">folder_open</mat-icon>
        <mat-error *ngIf="image.errors && (image.dirty || image.touched)">{{getImageMessage()}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div>
        <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="closeModal()">Cancelar</button>
        <button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="image.errors" type="submit">Aceptar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

TS (simplified)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FileValidator } from 'ngx-material-file-input';
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpEventType, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { WriteComponent } from './../../write/write.component';

import { RequestsService } from './../../services/requests.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-upload-image',
    templateUrl: './upload-image.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./upload-image.component.scss']
})
export class UploadImageComponent implements OnInit {
    private uploadImageURL = '/ajax/upload/image/';
    private state = 0;

    private urlForm: FormGroup;
    private imageForm: FormGroup;

    private regexUrl = 'https?://.+';

    private image: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, FileValidator.maxContentSize(5000000)]); // 5mb

    constructor(private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<WriteComponent>, private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.imageForm = new FormGroup({
            image: this.image
        });
    }

    private uploadImage() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('image', this.imageForm.get('image').value);
        this.http.post(this.uploadImageURL, formData).subscribe(output => {
            console.log('File transfered');
        });
    }
}
```

[Browser request](https://ibb.co/yXcT8yc)
The form data is Image: [object object], maybe that's the problem?

In the server i'm still getting req.files undefined

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible solutions for your problem.

1. Check whether you have set the 'Content-Type' of your server to receive **multipart/form-data**
2. Try to add a **type** eg., `<any>` here in your POST method,

   ```
   uploadImage(): Promise<any> {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', this.imageForm.get('image').value);
      return this.http.post(this.uploadImageURL, formData)
        .toPromise()
        .catch((e) => {
          // error
      });
   }
   ```

   As a key point, remove the **private** access modifier to make your POST method publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a few days i pull this out.

It was an error to assign this.image a value through template. I had to do it using a function and a new variable and then on submit assign that value to the 'image' field:

HTML

```
    <ngx-mat-file-input formControlName="image" placeholder="Imagen" accept="image/*" (change)="onFileChange($event)"></ngx-mat-file-input>
```

Ts

```
private imgFile;

private uploadImage() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', this.imgFile);
    this.req.uploadImage(formData).subscribe(output => {
        console.log(output);
    }, () => {
        console.log('Error');
    }, () => {
        console.log('Complete');
    });
}

private onFileChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        this.imgFile = file;
    } else {
        this.imgFile = null;
    }
}
```